# Making this slideToggle function cleaner

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I thank you in advance for reading my question.

I am new to any programming language.
I wrote some jQuery function that each div box opens and closes upon clicking.

My idea was to write code that will function whenever a div opens all the other divs close. 
It is pretty much functional but my code is too messy right now. 
I was wondering if anyone could give me some advice on cleaning this mess.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var open_footer = 'click to hide';
var close_footer = 'click to see detail';

$('.text_area').hide();
$('.text_area>img').remove(); 
$('.click_me:eq(0)').click(function(){

    $(this).next('.text_area').slideToggle(100, function(){
    if($(this).is(':visible')){
    $('.text_area:eq(1)').hide(); $('.text_area:eq(2)').hide()
       $('.text_area:eq(3)').hide();
    $('#article_footer1').text(open_footer);
    $('#article_footer2').text(close_footer);

    $('#article_footer3').text(close_footer);$('#article_footer4').text(close_footer);
    $('.text_area:eq(0)').append('<img class="text_area_img" src="Hicks_Nat.jpg" "no-repeat"/>');
    $('.text_area:eq(1)>img').remove();$('.text_area:eq(2)>img').remove();$('.text_area:eq(3)>img').remove();
    } else if ($(this).is(':hidden')){

        $('#article_footer1').text(close_footer);
        $('.text_area:>img').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

This is a one block of code and I basically have 3 more of similar blocks. 
Is there anyway I could simplify this?

Edit/ Here is the CSS

```
 .click_me{
display: block;
display: none;

padding:10px;
width: 550px;
float:left;
margin-top:15px;
margin-left: 25px;
height: 75px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
background:radial-gradient(center,circle,#EEEEE0 50%, white 80%);
opacity: 1;
border-radius:10px;
border: 1px solid silver;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-box-shadow:#999 2px 0px 3px;
box-shadow:rgb(110,110,110) 6px 6px 4px;
 }
.click_me:hover{
background: #DCDCDC;
 }
 .text_area{
font-family:arial;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 14px;
text-align:left;
background:white;
border: 1px solid silver;
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow:#999 2px 0px 3px;
margin-top:10px;
padding: 10px;
float:right;
max-height: 600px;
width: 500px;
overflow: auto;
```

}

Comment: could you post the html markup that goes with that?

Comment: Could you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that contains all of your code and update your question with the html as well?

Answer (score 0):

The way to clean up your code is with CSS primarily.  Since I don't know what your code looks like I took some guesses.  I didn't finish this, but the gist is there and should get you on your way to shortening/cleaning up your code:

CSS

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.openText:after {
    content: "click to hide";
}

.closeText:after {
    content: "click to see detail";
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="section hidden" style="border: 2px solid orange; padding: 3px;">
    <text-area class="text_area">First</text-area>
    <p>Some more text here or images or whatever</p>
</div>
<footer class="click_me article_footer"></footer>
<div class="section hidden" style="border: 2px solid orange; padding: 3px;">
    <text-area class="text_area">Second</text-area>
    <p>Some more text here for section 2</p>
</div>
<footer class="click_me article_footer"></footer>
<div class="section hidden" style="border: 2px solid orange; padding: 3px;">
    <text-area class="text_area">Third</text-area>
    <p>Section 3 additional stuff.</p>
</div>
<footer class="click_me article_footer"></footer>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function myToggle(ele) {
        $(ele).prev('div').toggleClass('hidden');
        $(ele).toggleClass('openText closeText');
    };

    $('.article_footer').addClass('closeText');
    $('.click_me').click(function() {
        var triggerElem = this;
        $('.openText').each(function() {
            if (this != triggerElem) {
                myToggle(this);
            }
        });
        myToggle(this);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. This looks a lot better. But each div adds pictures on click. Does this code also clear up the previously shown images?

Comment: No, I was just passing along some ideas. It's not nearly complete with what you want, but I figured it'd give you some ideas.